# How to send an array from a react Frontend to a mongo DB BackEnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

I have been building a recipe app (both front and back end). My issue is with the data structure and how to maintain it.

My recipe schema has a few properties that have an array of objects as values. On Postman, I am able to successfully maintain this structure by sending it like this {"categoryTags":["easy", "breakfast"]} and this creates a structure that looks like This: categoryTags: 0:"easy", 1:"breakfast"... This is great for mapping later on my frontend. The Information when retrieved on the frontend arrives like this: easy,breakfast and when edited and pushed to the db... it looks like this: categoryTags:0:"easy,breakfast". I don't know how to maintain the structure from the FE to the BE. Is this possible?

This is My React Code:

```
const EditRecipeModal = ({ recipe }) => {
  const oneRecipe = useSelector((state) => state.user.singleRecipe);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSingleRecipe(recipe._id));
  }, []);

  const [tags, setTags] = useState([recipe.categoryTags]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(recipe.title);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(recipe.description);
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState(recipe.ingredients);
  const [instructions, setInstructions] = useState(recipe.instructions);

  const editedModal = {
    categoryTags: tags,
    title: title,
    description: description,
    ingredients: ingredients,
    instructions: instructions,
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editRecipe(editedModal, `${recipe._id}`));
  };

  return (
    <div id="editRecipeModal">
      <h1>Edit {recipe.title}</h1>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
          <label className="fw-bold">Category</label>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => setTags(e.target.value)}
            value={tags}
            type="text"
            placeholder={recipe.categoryTags}
          />
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Title</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="ingredients"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Ingredients</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={ingredients}
              onChange={(e) => setIngredients(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="ingredients"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label className="fw-bold">Instructions</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={instructions}
              onChange={(e) => setInstructions(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              placeholder="instructions"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button
            className="login-80p mb-4 fw-bold"
            variant="success"
            type="submit"
          >
            Edit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default EditRecipeModal;
```

This is my BE Schema:

```
const recipeSchema = new Schema({
  categoryTags: [{ type: String, required: true }],
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  photo: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/135/135161.png",
  },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  ingredients: [{ type: String, required: false }],
  instructions: [{ type: String, required: false }],
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
});

export default model("Recipe", recipeSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define the categoryTags in the BE schema as array type `{ type: Array, required: true }`

Comment: Thank you for answering Marcia! Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem that I was having.